# copy images from one folder to sub folder in php

Tags: php

I am facing a problem. I have some images stored in D://Images. I have to copy these images into D://Images/Modified. I tried but I did not get any output.
This is my code:

```
define("BASE_IMAGE_PATH","D:\\");
define("IMAGE_FOLDER_NAME","2014finalfour\\");
define("IMAGE_FOLDER_NAME_MODIFIED","modified");
define("IMAGE_File_Path",BASE_IMAGE_PATH.IMAGE_FOLDER_NAME);
define("IMAGE_File_Path_Modified", BASE_IMAGE_PATH.IMAGE_FOLDER_NAME.IMAGE_FOLDER_NAME_MODIFIED);
$srcdir=constant("IMAGE_File_Path");
$destdir=constant("IMAGE_File_Path_Modified");
echo $destdir;
if (!file_exists(IMAGE_File_Path_Modified))
{
    mkdir(IMAGE_File_Path_Modified, 0777, true);
}
$srcdir=opendir($srcdir);
while($readFile = readdir($srcdir))
{
    if($readFile != '.' && $readFile != '..')
    {
        if (!file_exists($readFile)) 
        {
            if(copy($srcdir . $readFile, $destdir . $readFile))
            {
                echo "Copy file";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Canot Copy file";
            }
        }
    }
}
closedir($srcdir);
```

Please help me to sought out it. It says it can not copy the file. `copy() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given in C:\wamp\www\marcs\testmysql.php on line 3`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the copy() function :
`copy('foo/test.php', 'bar/test.php');`

example:

```
<?php
$file = 'images/folder/one.jpg';
$newfile = 'Images/folder/one_thumb.jpg';
if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
echo "failed to copy";
}
```

Makes a copy of the file source to dest.
If the destination file already exists, it will be overwritten.

Comment: first you can hardcode the path see in example and debug..if it's working or not...

Comment: Replace this line in your code:                                                                 if(copy("../folderName(source)/".$readFile, "../foldername(destination)/".$readFile))